# Position a list

Tags: html, css, reveal.js

I have a list that I need to position on a slide. With the css, I have moved the list-title `<h2>` to where I want it:

```
.reveal h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 240px;
}
```

The problem is I can't move the list to be under the `<h2>` list-title. Here is the list:

```
<section id="layout-example" class="slide level1">
<h1>Layout Example</h1>
<h2>
List title
</h2>
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

I have tried `.reveal ul {top: 220px`... etc. but the list is always in the same (wrong) position.

Where should I add what command in the css? I have made my own css by copying one of the examples included in reveal.js.

Comment: Try wrapping the `h2` and `ul` together with a div, and position the div how you were positioning the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute`, the element is taken out of the document flow. So your `<ul>` now "becomes the top-most element" in the flow, regardless of where `<h2>` is.

To make the `<ul>` flow after `<h2>`, don't use absolute positioning. Use:

```
h2 {
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-left: 240px;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 240px; /* assuming you want them to align left */
}
```

This ensures your `<ul>` follows your `<h2>`.

Alternatively, **IF*** you must use absolute positioning, also make `<ul>` absolutely positioned, e.g.:

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px; /* adjust as required */
    left: 240px;
}
```